# Vue Router in Weex

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, weex

I want to use vue router in weex, but now there is a problem:
"No component config for name:router-view, use default config". Thanks.

router.js

```
/*global Vue*/
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'

Vue.use(Router)

module.exports = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    }
  ]
})
```

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <text class="message">Now, let's use Vue.js to build your Weex app.</text>
</template>
```

index.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <image :src="logo" class="logo" />
    <text class="greeting">The environment is ready!</text>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Don't use the router view tag as self closing.Use it <router-view></router-view>

Comment: @ittus , thanks. But I don't know why, vue-router doesn't show up on the Xcode emulator, but it works on an Android device (real machine)。